TIMEZONE issues in apps deployed with SCDF
I've deployed locally with docker and tried different settings, but the timestamp of the task is not applied as I want.
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: dataflow-mysql
    platform: linux/amd64
    environment:
      LANG: en_US.utf8
      LC_ALL: en_US.utf8
      JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8'
      MYSQL_DATABASE: dataflow
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: rootpw
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'
      TZ: Asia/Seoul
    expose:
      - 3306
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro'
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro     # cent os
    command:
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci


  rabbitmq:
    image: rabbitmq:3.8-management
    container_name: dataflow-rabbitmq
    environment:
      LANG: en_US.utf8
      LC_ALL: en_US.utf8
      JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8'
      TZ: Asia/Seoul
    expose:
      - '5672'
      - '15672'
    ports:
      - '5672:5672'   # RabbitMQ 메시지 브로커 포트
      - '15672:15672' # RabbitMQ 관리 대시보드 포트
    volumes:
      - '/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro'
      - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro     # cent os



  dataflow-server:
    user: root
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-dataflow-server:${DATAFLOW_VERSION:-2.11.3-SNAPSHOT}${BP_JVM_VERSION:-}
    container_name: dataflow-server
    ports:
      - "9393:9393"
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Seoul
      - LANG=en_US.utf8
      - LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
      - METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_USER=admin
      - METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD=P@ssw0rd1!e
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
      # Set CLOSECONTEXTENABLED=true to ensure that the CRT launcher is closed.
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_TASK_SPRING_CLOUD_TASK_CLOSECONTEXTENABLED=true
      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_CLIENT_SERVER_URI=${SKIPPER_URI:-http://skipper-server:7577}/api
      # (Optionally) authenticate the default Docker Hub access for the App Metadata access.
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_CONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_REGISTRY_HOST={METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_HOST}
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_CONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_USER=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_USER}
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRY_CONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_SECRET=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRYCONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_USER=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_USER}
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_CONTAINER_REGISTRYCONFIGURATIONS_DEFAULT_SECRET=${METADATA_DEFAULT_DOCKERHUB_PASSWORD}
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow?permitMysqlScheme
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_DEFAULT_BINDER=rabbit
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_STREAM_SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest
    depends_on:
      - skipper-server
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_MOUNT_PATH:-.}:${DOCKER_MOUNT_PATH:-/home/cnb/scdf}
      - /home/workday:/home/workday
    command: ["java", "-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

  skipper-server:
    user: root
    image: springcloud/spring-cloud-skipper-server:${SKIPPER_VERSION:-2.11.3-SNAPSHOT}${BP_JVM_VERSION:-}
    container_name: skipper-server
    ports:
      - "7577:7577"
      - ${APPS_PORT_RANGE:-20000-20195:20000-20195}
    environment:
      - TZ=Asia/Seoul
      - LANG=en_US.utf8
      - LC_ALL=en_US.utf8
      - JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8
      - SERVER_PORT=7577
      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_PORTRANGE_LOW=20000
      - SPRING_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_PORTRANGE_HIGH=20190
      - LOGGING_LEVEL_ORG_SPRINGFRAMEWORK_CLOUD_SKIPPER_SERVER_DEPLOYER=ERROR
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/dataflow?permitMysqlScheme
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=root
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=rootpw
      - SPRING_JACKSON_TIME_ZONE=Asia/Seoul
      - SPRING_CLOUD_STREAM_DEFAULT_BINDER=rabbit
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_APPLICATIONPROPERTIES_STREAM_SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_HOST=rabbitmq
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PORT=5672
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_USERNAME=guest
      - SPRING_RABBITMQ_PASSWORD=guest
      # 추가된 설정: SCDF Global Deployment
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_TASK_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES=JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul
      - SPRING_CLOUD_DATAFLOW_STREAM_PLATFORM_LOCAL_ACCOUNTS_DEFAULT_ENVIRONMENT-VARIABLES=JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul

    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - mysql
      - rabbitmq
    volumes:
      - ${HOST_MOUNT_PATH:-.}:${DOCKER_MOUNT_PATH:-/home/cnb/scdf}
      - /home/workday:/home/workday
    command: ["java", "-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

It's showing a different timezone than the one I set.
When I access each container and check the timezone, I see that it is asia/seoul, so I want to know the reason and solution why the deployed app does not change.
I wanted the timezone to be asia/seoul, so I set it as above. Then I connected to the skipper server container and checked the following.

container date


$JAVA_OPTS



However, when I added the following code to the stream application and executed it, the result was not asia/seoul.
   log.info("Application Default Timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
   log.info("Application Current Time: " + LocalDateTime.now());

2024-11-26 01:13:06.128  INFO 801 --- [           main] c.i.f.FileSyncStartProcessor             : Application Default Timezone: Etc/UTC
2024-11-26 01:13:06.128  INFO 801 --- [           main] c.i.f.FileSyncStartProcessor             : Application Current Time: 2024-11-26T01:13:06.128474

Can you [edit] the question to include the code that generates that PNG file?  (Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.)  What thing has the wrong time zone?  There's a lot in the Compose file; can you reduce it to a [mcve], only showing the specific services and settings that are needed to demonstrate the issue?

What is the timezone of the docker host?

The docker is asia/seoul, but the application is outputting as Etc/UTC. I want the application to be asia/seoul as well.

With the experiments I performed you don't need to use -Duser.timezone you only need to set TZ in environment variables for workloads e.g. deployer.<app>.kubernetes.environment-variables: TZ=Asia/Seoul and you can add TZ in dataflow and skipper deployments. You can even configure a default environment variable in as part of dataflow and skipper deployments:
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.environmentVariables="TZ=Asia/Seoul"
spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.kubernetes.accounts.default.environmentVariables="TZ=Asia/Seoul"
For local deployments use local instead of kubernetes
When using local deployments you have the options to configure:
spring.cloud.skipper.server.platform.local.accounts.default.envVarsToInherit=TZ
spring.cloud.dataflow.task.platform.local.accounts.default.envVarsToInherit=TZ
Then the host platform TZ will be passed along.

Thanks. I solved it by giving the following options when deploying: “JAVA_OPTS=-Duser.timezone=Asia/Seoul -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dsun.jnu.encoding=UTF-8”
